# Nextjs API routes as API Gateway

Tags: next.js, api-gateway

In my microservices project I need a new layer as an API Gateway to change/add/check some data on almost all requests that are coming from the frontend (clientside) to my backend APIs. Mostly I would use this to check if a valid JWT is provided or a request is not malformed.

As the frontend a nextjs server is used in my project. Nextjs has the feature of API routes (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction).

I am wondering if you need a dedicated API Gateway if you just want to do basic stuff like checking if a request has a valid request body or a valid JWT is provided. After those checks I would forward or redirect the request to another microservice backend API endpoint.

If I use the Nextjs API route instead of a dedicated API Gateway:

- I dont need to manage an entirely new microservice in my project (the API Gateway for example build with Nodejs/Express)
- I dont need to bother with the same origin policy

For me this approach looks less complicated and since I have the nextjs server running anyway the API routes can be used with little to no effort.

Am I missing something?

Is it a good idea to use nextjs API routes as an API Gateway? Or should you stay with a dedicated API Gateway?

Comment: That's a perfectly valid use case for Next.js API routes. If it works for your requirements, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this approach in the past for similar reasons. Works a charm.

Things to consider:

- You will still need to validate your jwt token on the backend so proxy it through.
- If you are using OIDC oauth, consider using a library like nextJS auth0 library to protect your jwt tokens out in the wild in an encrypted cookie.
- You can use something like express-http-proxy to do some heavy lifting around proxying api requests through to your backend from nextjs.
- If you are using a logging framework like sentry, make sure to include frontend -> nextjs server -> backend as part of any distributed tracing correlation so you can trace errors through the layers.

Best of luck

Comment: Oh Re: request validation, i think your API needs to do that as well even if you want to pre validate in your NextJS layer. Might be just simpler at least to start with to do it in your API. ZOD is a good JS library i use for object validation. Can be used frontend or backend so you might get some reuse there.